# Exception with Java matrix

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, syntax

I'm getting ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException with this code, can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int[][] matrix = {{1,2,3,4},
                     {1,2,3,4}};

        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; i < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have no idea!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (int j = 0; i < matrix[i].length; j++) {
```

You are comparing with the wrong induction variable in the inner loop.  It should be this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
//              ^
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I spent an hour searching for a solution

Comment: Sometimes you just need another set of eyes. Happens to the best of us.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, in the inner loop, there should be "j" instead of "i".

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a homework, Java can make your life simpler.

```
int[][] matrix = {{1,2,3,4},
                 {1,2,3,4}};
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matrix));
```